# How to load Spring Beans only after an Object's properties are set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java-7

I have an object called `ApplicationProperties`. The object has private fields and public getter methods. Very trivial.

```
    if (properties == null) {
        properties = new ApplicationProperties();
        SettingsLoader settingsLoader = new SettingsLoader(properties);
        settingsLoader.loadApplicationSettings();
    }
    return properties;
```

I also have Spring Beans, some of which depend on `ApplicationProperties` for reading some path etc. This is working fine for a long period of time. The JDK is `Oracle JDK 1.6`. But recently when I deployed in `OpenJDK 1.7 ICEDTEA`
I got some `NullPointerException` as the application properties being used by a spring bean has null fields(Not initialized fully).

May be parallel class loading is done in case of Open JDK(Not sure about it).

How do I ensure that all spring beans(more than 200 in number - and many through annotations) are instantiated only after the `ApplicationProperties` is fully ready?

Answer (score 0):

Inject the properties object as a constructor dependency to all the beans that need it.

Comment: Actually some beans have static fields that set using some non bean classes(that use application properties).. Which is complicating things.

Comment: Is there any other approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The class `ApplicationProperties` is a non-bean which was not under the control of the Spring IoC. For some reasons the code which was working fine on `Oracle JDK 1.6` and higher versions but did not work on `Open JDK 1.7 ICEDTEA` and I was getting some `NullPointerException`.

For reference I am posting the solution as answer.

As the non-bean class properties need to be loaded completely before beans are created, I delegated the loading part to a separate thread and it worked fine for me.

```
public class SettingsLoader implements Runnable {
    //Other methods go here
    @Override
    public void run() {
        loadApplicationSettings();
    }
}
```

And inside the constructor of the `ApplicationProperties`

```
    private ApplicationProperties() {
        SettingsLoader settingsLoader = new SettingsLoader(this);
        Thread loader = new Thread(settingsLoader);
        loader.setName("Settings Loader");
        logger.info("Settings Loader is initiated. Loading application settings.");
        loader.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        try {
            loader.start();
            loader.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            logger.error("Application settings loader is interrupted. Exception is", ex);
        }
    }
```

With this the current thread waits until the thread `loader` has done its job of setting application properties fields.